# Unknown Error: Not reproducible Fatal Exception

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, exception

My app is experiencing a weird error which I cannot reproduce. I know the existence of this error because some users have reported it to me and I could catch it using the Fabric SDK.

Apparently it happens at any location, at any given time. It doesn't not happen a lot though, it seems to happen once in a while. I have no idea where to start looking for this, because I tried to catch the error running on multiple devices connected to my xcode project, but it just doesn't happen to me, or at least when I am looking for it. Can someone give me a light where to begin to look for it?

The stack trace:

```
    Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x18730afe0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x185d6c538 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x187311ef4 __methodDescriptionForSelector
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18730ef54 ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18720ad4c _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  Foundation                     0x187dff50c __NSThreadPerformPerform
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1872b942c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1872b8d04 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1872b69a8 __CFRunLoopRun
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1871e6da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
10 GraphicsServices               0x188c51074 GSEventRunModal
11 UIKit                          0x18d49ac9c UIApplicationMain
12 Otelo                          0x100230fc4 main (AppDelegate.swift:23)
13 libdyld.dylib                  0x1861f559c start

Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  Otelo                          0x1005bb308 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1572
1  Otelo                          0x1005bb308 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1572
2  Otelo                          0x1005bb1c4 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1248
3  Otelo                          0x1005aaa6c CLSHandler + 48
4  Otelo                          0x1005b9110 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 92
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1861c29a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1861cfee0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 84
7  Otelo                          0x1005b8ba4 CLSExceptionRecord + 212
8  Otelo                          0x1005b89cc CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 548
9  Otelo                          0x1005b85e0 CLSTerminateHandler() + 396
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x185d5b5d4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x185d5b1a8 __cxa_rethrow + 144
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x185d6c6f8 objc_exception_rethrow + 44
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1871e6e10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 532
14 GraphicsServices               0x188c51074 GSEventRunModal + 100
15 UIKit                          0x18d49ac9c UIApplicationMain + 208
16 Otelo                          0x100230fc4 main (AppDelegate.swift:23)
17 libdyld.dylib                  0x1861f559c start + 4
```

Comment: I think you have an `Unrecognized selector sent to instance` error. Does Fabric uploads the relevant console log to understand which class/method you are calling at crash time?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. That's all I have to work with